# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CommandAPI.Dtos.CommandReadDto>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Every time I test for the target action: `GetAllCommands()`, I face this error!

Here my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<CommandReadDto>> GetAllCommands()
{
      var commandItems = _repository.GetAllCommands();
      return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CommandReadDto>>(commandItems);//error-pane code
            
}
```

But when I return the result set as follow, it works correctly:

```
return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CommandReadDto>>(commandItems));
```

could anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the ActionResult types represent various HTTP status codes.

You have an `ActionResult<IEnumerable<CommandReadDto>>` endpoint return type, but you are trying to return an `IEnumerable<CommandReadDto>` with no defined code status, so it needs to be wrapped with `Ok()` or `NotFound()` methods, etc.

If you want to return `IEnumerable<CommandReadDto>`, then remove ActionResult from the return type and leave only `IEnumerable<CommandReadDto>` there, then it will work and automatically return status code 200

Comment: Thank You, do you prefer any documentations?

Comment: No, you just google "ActionResult Asp Net Core" and you can find information about it. Often you can find enough information in the official documentation from Microsoft